# React and pre-binding functions for performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just read this highly enlightening article today:

https://medium.com/@esamatti/react-js-pure-render-performance-anti-pattern-fb88c101332f

The article uses the following example to show how to pre-bind functions to prevent components from needless re-rendering:

```
class App extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
  }
  update(e) {
    this.props.update(e.target.value);
  }
  render() {
    return <MyInput onChange={this.update} />;
  }
}
```

This makes sense, though I can't figure out how to pass an argument to the function without using bind or `() => this.myFunc('some arg')`. Example:

```
  <div>
    <TextField
      floatingLabelText="Email"
      required
      value={this.state.email}
      onChange={e => this.setState({email: e.target.value})}
    />
  </div>
  <div>
    <TextField
      type="password"
      floatingLabelText="Password"
      required
      value={this.state.password}
      onChange={e => this.setState({password: e.target.value})}
    />
  </div>
```

I'm not sure how to refactor this to not use binding. I've got this class method as a starting point:

```
_textChange(field, value) {
  this.setState({
    [field]: value,
  });
}
```

But I'm not sure how to pass arguments into it from the `onChange` prop and follow the suggestions laid out by the article above.

Additionally, I have code that I've refactored into this:

```
export default OrgList = (props) => {
  const orgs = props.orgs.map((org) => {
    const addEditOrg = props.onAddEditOrg.bind(null, org, 'edit');
    const deleteOrg = props.onDeleteOrg.bind(null, org);

    return <TableRow key={org._id}>
      <TableRowColumn>{org.name}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>
        <IconButton onTouchTap={addEditOrg}>
          <ModeEdit />
        </IconButton>
        [...]
```

But I'm not sure if those pre-bound functions are in the right place. Do they need to be totally outside the component?

Comment: https://medium.com/@john1jan/react-binding-revealed-aa458df8c136#.fd5z0vmjl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to create separate methods which set email/password.

`linkState` is noop here, since it always returns different object. Same apply to higher order function (returning anonymous function as handler).

I would end up with this code. Event handlers are same, no unnecessary rendering is triggered this way.

```
setEmail(e) {
  this.setState({email: e.target.value})
}

setPassword(e) {
  this.setState({password: e.target.value})
}

<TextField
  onChange={this.setEmail}
/>

<TextField
  onChange={this.setPassword}
/>
```

Comment: Wow, that's highly unfortunate. What if I had 20 fields? It's a shame we have to choose between performance and code legibility.

Comment: PS: if you wouldn't mind, I added on a follow-up question above.

Comment: Yep, that's unfortunate. And when we have 20 fields like this,... you have to decide. If it's not causing performance problems, go with `linkState`. For elements which don't contain any children elements (input, ...) it should be no problem. To answer your extended question: yes. They should be bound outside of your component. Think of stateless function component as a render method in ES6 class or React's stateful component.

Comment: But in the second code example (with the map function), it's impossible to bind those functions outside the component, because the arguments passed depend entirely on the `org` object which changes on each iteration within `map`.

Comment: Why not just use `shouldComponentUpdate` and stick with binding functions in the event handlers like before?

Comment: Sorry, overlooked `map` call - jumped immediately onto `bind` calls. You're right. Not possible to do. `shouldComponentUpdate` should work.

Comment: Ahh I figured. In fact, now that I think about it, why wouldn't we just use `shouldComponentUpdate` for all checks, instead of pre-binding?

Comment: You could either pre-bind or implement `shouldComponentUpdate`. You write more code in both cases. It's up to your preference :)

Comment: Oh, just to clarify: the code you posted wouldn't actually work unless you pre-bound `this.setEmail` and `this.setPassword` in the constructor, yes?

Comment: Correct. For this reason I prefer `createClass`. Life's too short for `bind`... or I am just too lazy :D

Answer (score 4):

I use name attribute for this. Example:

```
handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}

<TextField
  name="email"
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>

<TextField
  name="password"
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```